# Cron job - update products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to update woocommerce products automatically every 30 minutes (example).

Ideally i would like to update only the products that their variation quantity has changed.
The reason for that is that we collaborate with another company that is responsible for a crm that handles the products and the quantities of them.
We also use polylang and polylang for woocommerce and when there is a change in a product quantity in a language, when we save that product, the same change happens to the other languages too (that is what we want, its the same store).

So when the other company updates the quantity of a product via woocommerce rest api, they dont actually save the new quantity, so the product is not actually updated. So the change happens only in one language and not on the others.
We have to go and manually save every product that changed so that the changes will apply to all the languages.

That's why i need a cron job, to save time from manually saving every product that changed.